# Using matplolib - Python

Tags: python

Trying to build a graph with using points from two lists:

`y - y[i]` and `x - y1[i]` for coordinates `y` and `x`. 
I'm trying to use pl.plot() function. But I'm lost how I can use it with points from my lists. Can you advice how I should do this?

My code is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import random
import math
import numpy as np
disp=0.8
m=0.5

y=[]
y1=[]
for i in range(200):
    y.append(0)
for i in range(100):
    y1.append(0)

i=0
for x in np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.005):
    f=pow(2.71,-((x-m)*(x-m)/(2*(disp))))/(math.sqrt((disp)*2.51))
    y[i]=f
    i=i+1
print("f1:",f)
i=0
for x in np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.05):
    f = 0.5 * (1 + math.erf((x - m) / (1.41 * math.sqrt(disp))))
    y[i]=f
    i=i+1
print("f2:",f)
#Do some operations with the values and then put them in y and y1 
#The loop is below. Sure, it is not right...
#Please,help..
for i in y:
    pl.plot([y[i]],[y1[i]])
pl.show()
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: _Please read the documentation for Matplotlib_. Before doing _anything_, read the docs! Before `append`ing in a loop, which wastes time and memory, read the docs! Before stuffing a heck of a lot of parentheses in an expression, which harms readability, read the docs! Before even _trying_ to plot a graph, read the docs! __Read the docs, dude, and may the Force be with you!__

Answer (score 0):

You should pass both lists to `plot`.

```
pl.plot(y, y1)
```

Also you can optimize all those loops where you're mutating `y` and `y1`. For example,

```
for x in np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.005):
    f=pow(2.71,-((x-m)*(x-m)/(2*(disp))))/(math.sqrt((disp)*2.51))
    y[i]=f
    i=i+1
```

easily translates to

```
y = np.apply_along_axis(
      lambda x: pow(2.71, -(x-m)*(x-m)/(2*disp))/math.sqrt(disp*2.51),
      0, 
      np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.005)
    )
```